# javascript inside storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdxjs

So my file extension is `.mdx` and I'm not sure if it allows me to include js code inside the `.mdx` file. I tried having it in the preview tag but it prints it as a string.

Below I have tried to write js code in a separate js file, import the function in the `.mdx` file, and use it, but it still won't work.

I also tried writing the `inline` function directly to the button `onclick` but had no luck.

Code:

```
<Preview>
 <div>
  <button onclick="onClickHandler">Click</button>
 </div>
</Preview>
```

Is there a way to include a small js code in `mdx` file.